# How to Remove Back Button in Unity Cardboard SDK

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Anyone have an idea of how I can remove the white back arrow that is rendered in the top left of the screen by default. Google is not turning anything up and the only thing I can find in the newest unitypackage is a call to DrawBackButton() in GvrPostRender under the legacy stuff.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible right now. I have tried to do this, and while searching in sdk i found this in `GvrPostRender`:

```
    if (vrMode) {
  DrawVRBackButton();
}
```

but then I checke this function and it looks like this:

```
  private void DrawVRBackButton() {
}
```

I aleso tried to simply remove this function from `if(vrMode)`, but this didn't work as well, so I guess we have to use it until they make it possible to turn off.